# How to get data from an input field and print it with the alert function?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm studying HTML, CSS, and Javascript at w3schools and I'm wondering how I can get data from info placed in text fields and print them using the alert function at the press of a button. (I'm currently developing a form for COVID contact tracing.

As for now, my form works; it can send data to a server for processing. It also has an alert pop-up that says, "Form Data submitted successfully!" But I want to change the pop-up to list the data that you have inputted. How can I do that?

(for reference, you can see my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>



<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Trebuchet, Arial; text-align: center;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
  width: 99%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  resize: horizontal;
}

h3 {
font-family: Tahoma;
color: black;
text-align: center;
font-size: 30px;

}; /* Form Title Font */

{
  background-color: #003cff;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;

  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #003cff;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Button's initial colors */

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #003bcf;
} /* The button changing color when hovered upon */

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  padding: 90px;
} /* The box's colors */


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
  <h3>Contact Tracing Form</h3>
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Input your first name">
    
    <label for="middlename">Middle Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="middlename" name="middlename" placeholder="Input your middle name">

    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Input your last name">


    <label for="region">Region</label>
    <select id="region" name="region">
    <option value="Empty">Select Region...</option>
      <option value="NCR">NCR</option>
      <option value="CAR">CAR</option>
      <option value="R1">Region 1 (Ilocos Region)</option>
      <option value="R2">Region 2 (Cagayan Valley)</option>
      <option value="R3">Region 3 (Central Luzon)</option>
      <option value="R4">Region 4-A (Calabarzon)</option>
      <option value="STR">Southwestern Tagalog Region (Mimaropa)</option>
      <option value="R5">Region 5 (Bicol Region)</option>
      <option value="R6">Region 6 (Western Visayas)</option>
      <option value="R7">Region 7 (Central Visayas)</option>
      <option value="R8">Region 8 (Eastern Visayas)</option>
      <option value="R9">Region 9 (Zamboanga Peninsula)</option>
      <option value="R10">Region 10 (Northern Mindanao)</option>
      <option value="R11">Region 11 (Davao Region)</option>
      <option value="R12">Region 12 (Soccsksargen)</option>
      <option value="R16">Region 16 (Caraga)</option>
      <option value="BARMM">BARMM (Bangsamoro)</option>
      <option value="None">I don't live in the Philippines</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Full Address</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" style="height:50px"></textarea> 
   <input type="submit" value = "Submit Form" onclick="myFunction()"></button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 alert("Form Data submitted successfuly!");
} // Pop-up script
</script>
  
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself. And welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to select the input fields you want by using JS:

```
let firstName = document.getElementById("firstname");
```

Use the .value Property to extract the text:

```
const firstNameData = firstName.value;
```

Do this for all the input fields.

Change the OnClick function to as follows:

```
function showAlert(){
alert(`Form Data submitted successfuly!\n
        First Name: ${firstNameData}`);
}
```

This is formatted strings in JavaScript.

**Example:**

```js
const siteName = "Stack Overflow";
console.log(`I love ${siteName}!`)
```